# Create an installer to install configure and run docker container

Tags: windows-installer, installation

I am trying to create an installer which installs docker then builds dockerfile and  opens the webpage hoseted by that dockerfile. What I'm trying to do

1. run Docker for Windows Installer
2. start Docker for Windows.exe and dockerd.exe
3. build my docker image and run

I tried below part using Execwait in NSIS but didn't work. Now it is a bat file.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\username\Desktop\docker\Docker for Windows Installer.exe"  -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath "‪C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Docker for Windows.exe"  -Wait
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\dockerd.exe"  -Wait
```

After running container with docker run below code does not start the website.

```
docker login -u=aaaaa -p=ppppp!!
docker build --tag example-flask .
docker run --name example-flask -d -p 5000:5000  
start http://localhost:5000/
```

My problem is none of those exe waits each other and after running docker run I can not open that website. Any suggestions?

Dockerfile

```
#use alpine linux with python 3.7
FROM python:alpine3.7 

#copy files from current directory to /app folder in container
COPY . /app

#cd into /app in container
WORKDIR /app

#install python modules
RUN pip install flask

# allow port 5000 on container
EXPOSE 5000
# run index.py
CMD python ./index.py
~~~
```

Comment: Can you add the Dockerfile you are building?

Comment: ~~~#use alpine linux with python 3.7
FROM python:alpine3.7 

#copy files from current directory to /app folder in container
COPY . /app

#cd into /app in container
WORKDIR /app

#install python modules
RUN pip install flask

# allow port 5000 on container
EXPOSE 5000
# run index.py
CMD python ./index.py
~~~

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the Dockerfile, that makes it more readable. And the code for index.py might also be relevant.

Comment: Yeap, just modified.

Comment: Can you run docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash and check if the app is running on port 5000 inside the docker container?

Comment: If I run those things my container is running. My issue is I can't run all those exes in sequence automatically via installer. I am trying to create an installer which instals docker first then builds the docker file then runs it.

Comment: Oh so it is not related to docker not exposing the port. Shouldn't you tag the question with powershell then? It is more of a powershell question than a docker question.

Comment: Hi @Blokje5 sorry for my confusion. I tried doing same thing with powershell, nsis and advancedinstaller. None of them worked. Only docker was common so I tagged it with docker tag. May be I can tag it as installer.

Comment: @Ayshine, did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: @schoon sadly, no.